# Rails 6 cookies are not being updated in devlopment (only firefox and Chrome)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, session-cookies, csrf

I currently have loads of problems setting cookies in a Rails 6 app. 
This only happens in Development when accessing via localhost. Via ngrok tunnel it is working witout problems.

Does anybody else have this problem? (I already downgraded chrome from v80) but as it is also not working in Firefox, I am not sure what is going on.

In Safari cookies (and then session as well) are being set without problems. I am beginning to thing this might have something to do with the sameSite policy.

Alos not using API mode or something.

Answer (score 2):

So it tuned out to be related to the Shopify_app gem! 
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/891

Answer (score 0):

ActionDispatch added a configuration option for the `SameSite` setting in version 6.1 (documentation [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-dispatch)).

If you have it set like this in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :none
```

Your sessions will no longer work in development. This is because Chrome expects `SameSite=None` cookies to also be marked as secure.

In order for your sessions to work during development in Chrome, you need to set the same configuration option to `:lax` in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :lax
```